# webpack 4 warns of invalid configuration object when specifying multiple entry points as objects

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I'm trying to split my app into two chunks that depend on the same module. I'm following the official webpack docs, that describe how this can be achieved by creating multiple entry points, like so:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: {
            import: "./src/index.js",
            dependOn: "oidcclient"
        },
        callback: {
            import: "./src/callback.js",
            dependOn: "oidcclient"
        },
        oidcclient: "./src/oidc-client"
    },
    ...
```

The above configuration gives me the following error when I try to build:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.entry should be one of these:
   function | object { <key>: non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string | [non-empty string]
   -> The entry point(s) of the compilation.
   Details:
    * configuration.entry['callback'] should be a string.
      -> The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
    * configuration.entry['callback'] should be an array:
      [non-empty string]
      -> A non-empty array of non-empty strings
    * configuration.entry['callback'] should be one of these:
      [non-empty string]
      -> All modules are loaded upon startup. The last one is exported.
    * configuration.entry['callback'] should be one of these:
      non-empty string | [non-empty string]
      -> An entry point with name
```

If I remove the entry point for callbackk, and keep index along with oidcclient, I then receive a similar error for index instead of callback.

I'm pretty much copy pasting an example from the official docs, which leaves me confused as to what might be causing this. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of the problem is: you use a feature of webpack v5.

So, you have two ways to solve the problem:

1. revert the values in the `entry` back to **strings**, and use this feature to split the chunks:

   - [Prevent Duplication](https://v4.webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#prevent-duplication) (for webpack v4).
2. upgrade webpack to v5 (it's still in BETA state at the moment);